# Passing coordinates to HTML page to open Google Street View in new window

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a separate mapping application that reads the current center of the map and grabs the lat and long and then passes those variable to an HTML page.
Here is the code for the HTML page and its javascript. This opens a new window but does not show the street view and does not give an error.

```
  var lat = getParameterByName('lat');
  var lon = getParameterByName('lon');

  var panorama;
  function initialize() {
    panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById('street-view'),
        {
          position: {lat: ""+lat+"", lng: ""+lon+""}, //bad code???
          pov: {heading: 165, pitch: 0},
          zoom: 1
        });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
     src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBaSDR10ovsZ0rxygIpheEgrR2YjpbJHbg&callback=initialize">
</script>
```

Comment: Don't you get a javascript error in the console: `InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number` (lat/lng are strings, not numbers when you prepend/append "" to them)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "" from the [google.maps.LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngLiteral) and probably be prudent to use `parseFloat` on those strings).

**code snippet:**

```js
var lat = 40.713613; // getParameterByName('lat');
var lon = -74.006757; // getParameterByName('lon');

var panorama;

function initialize() {
  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('street-view'), {
      position: {
        lat: parseFloat(lat),
        lng: parseFloat(lon)
      },
      pov: {
        heading: 165,
        pitch: 0
      },
      zoom: 1
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#street-view {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="street-view"></div>
```